# how to classify my dataframe based on the genres i want using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv data file with different genres of games. There are games with 3 or 4 genre tags to it in the .csv file. How do I extract the rows which have only 2 of the 4 genre parameters? I want to extract only the rows which have genres of `Games` and `Strategy`?

I have tried `df2 = df1[df1['Average User Rating']>4]` this for extracting the ratings above 4 but i am not able to figure out a way to extract from the genre. Kindly please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df3 = df1[df1['Genres'].str.contains('Games') & df1['Genres'].str.contains('Strategy') & (df1['Genres'].str.count(',') == 1)]
```

Comment: hey! thank you, but when i tried this it is still not giving me only the genres with games and strategy in it.

Comment: @PrajwalKumarss I've added now a condition that there is only 1 comma, meaning there are only 2 genres, the 2 you are looking for.

Comment: this worked! thank you soo much for helping with my query. cheers!